# Issues in integrating Flutter Firebase phone authentication for iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I know this question has been asked several times but none of them helped me resolve my issue. I followed everything that is mentioned in the docs to configure Firebase Auth to iOS. Plus I am using Flutter for the app development.

This is the dart code for verifying the phone number:

```
await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: _phoneNumberController.text,
        timeout: const Duration(minutes: 2),
        verificationCompleted: (user) {
          print('verification completed');
        },
        verificationFailed: (AuthException authException) {
          _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text(
                'Phone number verification failed. Code: ${authException.code}. Message: ${authException.message}'),
          ));
        },
        codeSent: (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) {
          _verificationId = verificationId;
          _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: const Text(
                'Please check your phone for the verification code.'),
          ));
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
          _verificationId = verificationId;
        });
```

When I provide a phone number and verify it, it gives me an error message saying:

> If app delegate swizzling is disabled, remote notifications received by UIApplicationDelegate need to be forwarded to FIRAuth's canHandleNotification: method.

Since I'm using Flutter, I just pasted the below code to the AppDelegate.swift which I am not sure if it is correct or not. I will paste the entire class below:

```
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

    //return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    return true
  }

    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        // Pass device token to auth
        Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.prod)

        // Further handling of the device token if needed by the app
        // ...
    }

    override func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                              didReceiveRemoteNotification notification: [AnyHashable : Any],
                              fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(notification) {
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.noData)
            return
        }
        // This notification is not auth related, developer should handle it.
    }

    // For iOS 9+
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL,
                              options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
        if Auth.auth().canHandle(url) {
            return true
        }
        // URL not auth related, developer should handle it.
        return true;
    }
}
```

What I have tried so far:

1. Created an App Id with push notifications enabled, generated a key and profile in Apple Developer account
2. Uploaded the key to the Firebase console under iOS app
3. configured custom URL Schemes in Xcode for reCaptcha, enabled push notification and background remote notification under Xcode capabilities
4. Added the above specified code to the AppDelegate.swift
5. Cleaned and ran the project

version infos:

- firebase-core: 0.3.0^2
- firebase-auth: 0.8.1+4

I might have missed some info but I tried my best to include all the necessary stuffs.

Any solution/idea to solve this would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @Renziera Unfortunately, I still have not been able to find any solution for this

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been while, but recently i've the same problem in a flutter/iOS project with recent version and i solved that way:

my firebase flutter packages versions:

```
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.3.3
  firebase_analytics: ^10.4.3
  firebase_app_check: ^0.1.4+3
  firebase_auth: ^4.6.3
  firebase_core: ^2.14.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.8.2
  firebase_remote_config: ^4.2.3
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^5.3.3
  firebase_messaging: 14.4.1
```

1 - Add into info.plist > FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to true(i think it's optional set true):

```
    <key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
    <true/>
```

in the AppDelegate

2 - import:

```
import FirebaseMessaging
import FirebaseAuth
```

3 - add apnstoken from your app to auth lib:

```
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .unknown)
    }
```

4 - then add application didReceiveRemoteNotification who is responsible to receive message when your app is in background

```
override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        if (firebaseAuth.canHandleNotification(userInfo)){
            completionHandler(.noData)
            return
        }
    }
```